# postLink generates invalid code at CakePHP 2.3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I am using CakePHP 2.3

I have two environments where I have my web application. At the testing environment with the exact same version of the application (all files are the same) I am having a problem with the `Form->postLink` method.

It shows this error on the Javascript console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'submit' users:119
>   onclick

Comparing the resulting HTML from both environments I can notice that the attributes `name` and `id` generated by this method are repeated more than once in the same page (which shouldn't be like that).

This is the code use to generate those post links:

```
foreach($users as $user){   
    $delete = $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array('action' => 'delete', $user['user_id']), __('Are you sure you want to delete %s?', $user['user_id']));
}
```

This is the problematic generated HTML with repeated values for `id` and `name` as you can see:

```
<!-- link 1 -->
<form action="delete/1/" name="post_51e8019d095f1" id="post_51e8019d095f1" style="display:none;" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/>
</form>

<a href="#" onclick="if (confirm(&#039;Are you sure you want to delete blabla?&#039;)) { document.post_51e8019d095f1.submit(); } event.returnValue = false; return false;">Delete</a>



<!-- link 2 -->
<form action="delete/2/" name="post_51e8019d095f1" id="post_51e8019d095f1" style="display:none;" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/>
</form>

<a href="#" onclick="if (confirm(&#039;Are you sure you want to delete blabla22?&#039;)) { document.post_51e8019d095f1.submit(); } event.returnValue = false; return false;">Delete</a>
```

Why is this happening? 
Could it be related with the configuration of the web server somehow? I don't see another explanation for it...

Thanks.

Comment: The only issue I can see is the second parameter in the `postLink()` method. It should be something like `array('action' => 'delete', $user['User']['user_id'])`.

Comment: @CrisSawfish is not a problem. I am working with Oracle and procedures instead of with CakePHP models so the structure is different.

Comment: The postLink() method creates a unique id for the form as you can see at the [source](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/source-class-FormHelper.html#1760) and it does it correctly. I'm using it also with the latest version of CakePHP. So It has got to be something else inside your `foreach` loop maybe.

Comment: @CrisSawfish something is going wrong but I don't know what it is. Here's the loop code Cris: http://pastebin.com/VRe4uaad

Comment: So this is definitely **not** a problem of `postLink()`. I just tested  your loop in my system (development enviroment configuration) and it works just fine! Since the form id is created using current microtime (check [uniqid function](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)), maybe there is something going on with your php settings?

Comment: @CrisSawfish that's what I was asking. As I can also see it works perfectly in one of my 2 environments. But I have no idea which configuration can affect this method...

Comment: May be problem in the Html structure.. Example A form is opened inside that form you have this postlink lines.. Then the opened form got closed..Form open and close not prober u will face this issue.. Or change ur security to low and check

Comment: @Cakephp.Saint it seems everything is ok. How could you explain then that it works well in one environment and not in the other? I've compared the resulting HTML and the **only** difference is the `name` and `id` of those forms as well as those same values before the `.submit()` js event. Something is crashing the `postLink` function...

Comment: @CrisSawfish you might be right, it can be related with an IIS issue and `uniqid`: http://samjlevy.com/2013/05/php-uniqid-not-unique-on-iis-7-5/ I might have to modify the `postLink` source code adding a second parameter.

Comment: There is still problem with postLinks generated in loop. It does not work for the very first form click!

Comment: check the last updated in the accepted answer. That's the solution taken by newer versions of CakePHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by a bug in IIS 7.0.6000.16386 and the PHP function [`uniqid`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) as pointed out [here](https://samjlevy.com/php-uniqid-not-unique-on-iis-7-5/).

I am using a slightly different version in both environments ( IIS 7.0.6000.16386 vs IIS 7.5.7600.16385) and that was the cause of the problem.

In order to solve it I modified the file `lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php` chaning the line `$formName = uniqid('post_');` inside the `postLink` function to:

```
$formName = uniqid('post_', true);
```

That adds more entropy and as the documentation says:

> If set to TRUE, uniqid() will add additional entropy (using the combined linear congruential generator) at the end of the return value, which increases the likelihood that the result will be unique.

## Update

Ended up having to add one more change due to problems with javascript in forms.
I added one more line after `$formName = uniqid('post_', true);` so it looks like:

```
$formName = uniqid('post_', true);
$formName = str_replace('.', '', $formName);
```

Comment: Well that was a long shot!! I thought about proposing what you did but there was no way for me to test it out! Anyway I'm glad it worked out for you. We'll definitely keep in mind situations like that